# Bootstrap table-striped get td value by click

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a table `table-striped` and in which row there is a delete button. When the user click in the delete button, a modal dialog show askig id the user really want to delete that row.

I need to get the value to be delete, how could I get id `td`?

```js
function modalAvisoExclusao() {
  $('#confirmaExclusao').modal('show');
}

function excluirUO() {
  $('#confirmaExclusao').modal('hide');
  var table = $('#Lista').DataTable();
  var d = table.cell(this).data();
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="modal fade" id="confirmaExclusao" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="confirmDeleteLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Dele&ccedil;&atilde;o Permanente</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Deseja realmente excluir este registro ?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="confirmUo" onclick="excluirUO();">Excluir</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel-body">
    <table id="Lista" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#alterarModal" onClick="">
                                            <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></i> Alterar
                                        </button>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#excluirModal" onClick="modalAvisoExclusao();">
                                            <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i> Excluir
                                        </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$170,750</td>
          <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#alterarModal" onClick="">
                                            <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></i> Alterar
                                        </button>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#excluirModal" onClick="modalAvisoExclusao();">
                                            <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i> Excluir
                                        </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why don't you use datatables? It's way easier to get any data you want from a table!

Comment: But I'm using. This one: https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap

Comment: Have you checked this https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/api/get.html ?

Comment: I'm using : `var table = $('#Lista').DataTable();  var d = table.cell( this ).data();` . The variable `d` is undefined.

Comment: can you please share the code via JS Fiddle?

Comment: Yes, I can. Link : https://jsfiddle.net/g2cpd845/1/

Comment: You're apparently loading DataTables twice in that demo.

Comment: It was a mistake. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ligneSel` to get the data you want. It's an array.

```js
var table = $('#Lista').DataTable({
  select: 'single'
});
//Get selected row data
$('#Lista tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  ligneSel = table.row(this).data();
  $('#user_').html(ligneSel[0]);
  alert(ligneSel)
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.25/datatables.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.25/datatables.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="modal fade" id="confirmaExclusao" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="confirmDeleteLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Dele&ccedil;&atilde;o Permanente</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Deseja realmente excluir este registro <span id="user_"></span>?</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="confirmUo">Excluir</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">
      <table id="Lista" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#alterarModal">
                <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></i> Alterar
              </button>

              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmaExclusao">
                <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i> Excluir
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#alterarModal" onClick="">
                <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></i> Alterar
              </button>

              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#excluirModal">
                <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i> Excluir
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! It's running.